# SQL QUERY--Need help in finding a particular percentage

Tags: sql

There are two tables with the below columns:

```
table1: asin_details(asin,contact_id) primary key: contact_id
table2: contact_details(contact_date,contact_id,hmd_response(y or n)) primary key: contact_id
```

I've to find specific percentage from the above data using a formula called no. of n's/no. of y's *100 which is called as `"FRR"`

So, the actual question is to find the "FRR" of all the asin's with which customers contacted us between `01-jan-2013 and 31-dec-2013`

I'm actually struggling with the part where you need to calculate the `"FRR"` from the date provided above. Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (( select count(hmd_response) from contact_details where hmd_response= 'n')/( select count(hmd_response) from contact_details where hmd_response= 'y') )*100 as FRR
from asin_details A
join contact_details C
on c.contact_id = A.contact_id
where contact_date between '01-jan-2013' and '31-dec-2013'
```

OR

```
SELECT ( ( select count(hmd_response) from contact_details where hmd_response= 'n' 
AND between '01-jan-2013' and '31-dec-2013')/
( select count(hmd_response) from contact_details where hmd_response= 'y' 
AND between '01-jan-2013' and '31-dec-2013') )*100 as FRR
```

Try this out and let me know.

I am basically calculating the counts of y's and n's and then i am calculating the FRR.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Had no idea that it could be so simple. Guess I need more practice. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
SELECT
a.asin,
((count(case c.hmd_response when 'n' then 1 end) / 
count(case c.hmd_response when 'y' then 1 end)) * 100) as FRR,
a.contact_id
from asin_details a
join contact_details c
on a.contact_id = c.contact_id
where c.contact_date between '01-jan-2013' and '31-dec-2013'
```